# why ignite cluster unbalanced load?

Tags: load, ignite

I have a pressure test on 3 nodes, but only one CPU is very high, others are very low. Ignite cluster with TCP discovery,I have a jdbc connection like:
jdbc:ignite:thin://172.16.14.15,172.16.14.16,172.16.14.17/

Comment: Do you have persistence? Are all 3 of your nodes in Baseline Topology?

Comment: I have persistence and all 3 of nodes in Baseline Topology

Comment: Can you collect thread dumps from all nodes under load, post them somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC will try to establish a connection to one of the specified servers one by one until it manages to connect. You can't rely on it if you want an even connection distribution. What kind of SQL queries do you use, btw?

Comment: JDBC could load balance? One node is near 100, others are near 0. my sql is insert into a table with jdbc, so result is terrible when CPU is hige

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work properly in 2.8: [IGNITE-11471](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11471)

Comment: when can use for 2.8? 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT can instead of 2.8?

Comment: I think 2.8 will be released on Feb, 2020. You could try to switch to a regular think client instead https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/net-sql-api#sqlfieldsqueries

Comment: Partition-awareness feature is already available in GridGain Community Edition for JDBC (install 8.7.9 version): https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/JDBC/jdbc-driver#partition-awareness

Comment: thanks, I have a try, but no use. It's always on same node.

Answer (score 0):

I have a try with LB, every node's CPU is similar, but I don't known whether this is a right way.